# How can i redirect no-logged user from all urls? PassportJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local-mongoose

I'm doing a web app with nodeJS and for the authentication I'm using PassportJs with passport-local-mongoose.

I make this snippet for the root route to check if the user is logged in

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res){

    if(req.isAuthenticated()){


    List.find({}, function(err, results){

        if(!err){
            res.render('home');
        }});   

    }else{
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

so my question is: there's a way to redirect the user to the login page if they are non-logged, from all URLs without specifying it in all the routes get.

Comment: try using [middlewares functions](https://expressjs.com/fr/guide/using-middleware.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express comes up with `middlewares`. Basically, a `request` pass through all `middlewares` that match its path and http method. You can do whatever you want in a middleware, then either send a `response` or pass the request to the next `middleware`.

```
// All get requests
app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
    // If not authenticated
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }

    // Else,  go to the next middleware
    next();
}

// Real business here
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    List.find({}, function(err, results){
        if(!err){
            res.render('home');
        }});   
    }
});
```

You can read more here : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html